# gitignore does not ignore files

Tags: git, gitignore

[image]
The image says it all. Why is git telling me that I've changed the file when I'm explicitly telling it to ignore it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `.gitignore` specifies files that should not be added to `git`'s index. It does not prevent changes to files that are already in the index.

If you want to remove the file completely from the index, you will need to commit a deletion of that file. Then if the file gets recreated (and it is still listed in `.gitignore`), it will not be re-added to the index.

Answer (score 3):

you have to remove it from the repository and then commit it.

```
git rm -rf --cached .idea/*
git add -A .
git commit -m "Removed idea files"
git push
```

And now all your `.idea` files will be ignored (if added to the `.gitignore` as described above).

Answer (score 1):

You may have added the file previously, making it tracked. If it gets added to the `.gitignore` file after that, Git will still report changes to it because it is a tracked file.

You need to remove the file from the index and create a new commit.